# Can I setup two Fuseki instances using the same database directory?

Tags: fuseki

I need to have a public read only instance to query data using the port 3030 and a private read and write instance to add and update data using the port 3031. Both instances are only accessible throw a web server using distinct domains and port 80. Also, the private instance provides access using an HTTP user/password.

My question is about concurrency: Has Fuseki support to concurrently access to a directory database using two server instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Fuseki documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/tdb_transactions.html):

> Multiple applications, running in multiple JVMs, using the same file
>   databases is not supported. There must be a single JVM controlling the
>   database directory and files.
>
> Use Fuseki to provide a database server for multiple applications.
>   Fuseki supports SPARQL Query, SPARQL Update and the SPARQL Graph Store
>   protocol.

So, the answer is that multiple instances using the same database are not supported.